# Get form data after POST with .ajax()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

After submitting a form via ajax, I want to get the data that I passed into the form and put it in a JS variable.

```
<form>
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: form.attr('action'),
           data: form.serialize(),
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data); 
           }
         });

    event.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

So how do I get the data (e.g. what the person posted into input) processed via POST and put it in a JS variable? NOTE: I do *NOT* want to get the input via input.val(), It *MUST* be the data submitted into the databse.

Comment: you doesnt specify form action in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your server side code you will receive the posted data in `$_POST` variable.So if you want to receive it back in the response then simply post it back to the ajax request.

Try

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

And also change the dataType of your ajax like this

```
dataType : 'json'
```

And in your ajax success  try `console.log(data)` to see the response and check your browser console

Comment: I added that and then when I submit, nothing happens...but the form is getting submitted as I'm seeing new entries in the database.